# ng2-ckeditor toolbars were not working properly

Tags: angular, ckeditor

I am working on a project where I have to implement CKEditor in angular 4 project. I have used [this](https://github.com/chymz/ng2-ckeditor) editor for my project. Now it happened that letest version(1.2.0) of CKEditor is giving me error. So I downgraded it (to 1.1.9). I am getting it working. Good but what happens here is when ever I am trying to use any toolbar, it doesn't work. I tried image toolbar as shown in below image. I am trying to insert link to it but I am not able to insert anything in any of the textbox.

[image]

I am not even getting error. Anything that I am missing?

Here is my code that I am using :

**html**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <ckeditor formControlName="Description" #myckeditor [config]="ckeConfig" debounce="500">
  </ckeditor>
</div>
```

**TS FIle**

```
export class myclass implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild("myckeditor") ckeditor: any;
    ckeConfig: any;
    ngOnInit(){
        this.ckeConfig = {
            allowedContent: true
        };
}
```

**EDIT :**

Found out that I have been using CKEditor in popup. So this is the reason I am not able to use all the properties. So I guess now need to figure out anything that I can use that can make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Found out the workaround for this issue :

In your angular project you must've maintained js. All you need to do is put this code inside that. And load it before you use Modal Popup.

```
$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function() {
    $( document )
        .off( 'focusin.bs.modal' ) // guard against infinite focus loop
        .on( 'focusin.bs.modal', $.proxy( function( e ) {
            if (
                this.$element[ 0 ] !== e.target && !this.$element.has( e.target ).length
                // CKEditor compatibility fix start.
                && !$( e.target ).closest( '.cke_dialog, .cke' ).length
                // CKEditor compatibility fix end.
            ) {
                this.$element.trigger( 'focus' );
            }
        }, this ) );
};
```

This will make ckeditor work. Although it's very much unorthodox.